# Determine the Laplace transform given:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

How can you perform the following transformation?
$$\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}\left\{\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{-3t}\sin(2t)}{t}\,dt\right\}
\end{equation}
$$
I'm not sure how to use the convolution.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\int_0^t f(x)dx\right)(s) = \frac{\mathcal L(f(t))(s)}{s}$$ (integration by parts) and also, $$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{f(t)}{t}\right) = \int_s^\infty \mathcal{L}(f(t))(z)dz$$ and $$\mathcal{L}(e^{at}\sin(bt))$$ is standard.

Comment: Could you help me a little more? ... or some material to support me?

Comment: @SantiagoSeeker Here is a table I found on google that has the three relevant pieces (and many other identities). http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf (see 31,32 and 19).

Comment: @SantiagoSeeker You apply the three identities to your transform (in that order). (Then for good measure you can do the integral $\int_s^\infty$). For instance application of the first identity gives $$ \mathcal{L}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\sin(2t)e^{-3t}}{t}dt\right) = \frac{1}{s} \mathcal L \left(\frac{\sin(2t)e^{-3t}}{t}\right)$$ and then you can apply the second to write this as an integral over the function $\mathcal L(\sin(2t)e^{-3t}).$

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b>0$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(at)e^{-bt}}{t}\,dt=\arctan\frac{a}{b} \tag{1}$$
hence the Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin(2t)e^{-3t}}{t}$ is given by $\arctan\frac{2}{3+s}$ and the wanted Laplace transform is given by $\frac{1}{s}\arctan\frac{2}{3+s}$. $(1)$ can be derived from
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(at)e^{-bt}\,dt \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\tag{0} $$
by integrating both sides with respect to $a$.